# Stop displaying normal tooltips when using easytooltip

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, tooltip

I'm trying to use easytooltip to create tooltips that don't disappear in IE. I can get the tooltips to appear but the problem is on area tags the old tooltips are always visible.

Is there any way to hide them?

Alternatively, does anyone know of a working alternative to easytooltip that won't cause IE to complain about the script being too slow.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find a solution here: http://cssglobe.com/post/4380/easy-tooltip--jquery-plugin (look for the comment of "oakesy54")